# How to automatically apply ISBN hyphenation?

Tags: isbn, hyphenation

I've got ISBN numbers (10-digits and 13 digits) without the dashes.
Now I'm looking for a way to add those dashes automatically.

I found some useful information here:
http://www.isbn.org/standards/home/isbn/international/hyphenation-instructions.asp

But I'm not sure if it's doable at all, because the
publisher identifier has a random length, and without
knowing it, it's maybe not possible to determine the
correct positions for the dashes.

Does anybody know if it's possible somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can deduce the length of the publisher identifier if you have the [full range tables](https://www.isbn-international.org/range_file_generation).

Example 1. ISBN 0141439564 (Penguin: *Great Expectations*)

- The group identifier is 0 (English language).
- The publisher ranges for this group are 00–19, 200–699, 7000–8499, 85000–89999, 900000-949999, and 9500000–9999999
- The next two digits are 14, which is in the range 00–19, so the publisher has 2 digits.
- So the hyphenated form is 0-14-143956-4

Example 2. ISBN 2253004227 (Poche: *Germinal*)

- The group identifier is 2 (French language)
- The publisher ranges for this group are 00–19, 200–349, 35000–39999, 400–699, 7000–8399, 84000–89999, 900000–949999, 9500000–9999999
- The next three digits are 253, which is in the range 200–349, so the publisher has 3 digits
- So the hyphenated form is 2-253-00422-7

You can check your algorithm at the Library of Congress's [ISBN hyphenation tool](https://www.loc.gov/publish/pcn/isbncnvt_pcn.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your input. I've found this now, and was wondering if there's a way to determine the positions for the dashes without using the full library:
http://isbntools.com/details.html

Comment: I believe you need the full range tables, because the publisher ranges are different for each group.

Comment: Yeah, I feared that. xD
Thanks anyway - makes it a bit more complicated then.

Comment: Library of Congress gave error that it cannot hyphenate, but [ISBN official website's tool](https://www.isbn.org/ISBN_converter) helped

Answer (score 5):

For Python, you can use the library [python-stdnum](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-stdnum), [isbnid](http://code.google.com/p/isbnid/) or [isbn_hyphenate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbn_hyphenate). They can hyphenate ISBNs, and use the range table mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following JavaScript function to hyphenate ISBNs (I know there is also [isbnjs](https://code.google.com/p/isbnjs/), but this is more compact and easier to include in other projects I think).

https://gist.github.com/aurimasv/6693537

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbntools, it will allow you to 'hyphenate' ISBNs and much more, like extracting, cleanning, transforming, and get metadata.

This is a library (that you can use in your program) but it installs several 'scripts' that you can use from the command line.