# Is there an easy way to add dashes to an ISBN in Python?

Tags: python, isbn

I have a column of 13 digit ISBN numbers (e.g. 1234567890123) saved as strings. To display them in a report, I need to add hyphens, e.g. (123-4-567-89012-3). I use a function to add the dashes before displaying, e.g.

```
def format_isbn(isbn):
    return isbn[0:3] + "-" + isbn[3] + "-" + isbn[4:7] + "-" + isbn[7:12] + "-" + isbn[12]
```

Is there a simpler way that I'm missing, perhaps by using string formatting?

Comment: Is there any specific pattern after which you want to add hyphens?

Comment: It varies depending on publisher. For my publisher, the pattern is the one above - 3-1-3-5-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically apply ISBN hyphenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154708/how-to-automatically-apply-isbn-hyphenation)

Comment: Thanks, Georgy. My needs are pretty simple in this case, so I didn't really look into any third party libraries, but some of these are pretty useful.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, aside from maybe using `"-".join()`:

```
return "-".join([isbn[0:3], isbn[3], isbn[4:7], isbn[7:12], isbn[12]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that. The use of join is neater, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use string formatting as mentioned:

```
return f"{isbn[0:3]}-{isbn[3]}-{isbn[4:7]}-{isbn[7:12]}-isbn[12]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub` here for a regex option:

```
isbn = "1234567890123"
output = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{5})(\d{1})', '\\1-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5', isbn)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
123-4-567-89012-3
```

Comment: Thanks That approach is easier than counting the characters in string slicing..

Comment: @Mackrell I checked the other answers, and mine requires about 70 characters of typing, while AKX`s answer only needs 53, so what I gave is more verbose at least in that regard.

Comment: Yeah, but counting the characters took me longer than typing those extra 17 characters!

Answer (score 0):

`struct.unpack` would be nice if it didn't force you to work with a `bytes` value.

```
import struct


def format_isbn(n: str):
    fmt = struct.Struct("3s s 3s 5s s")
    return b'-'.join(fmt.unpack(n.encode())).decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot.

ISBN-13 use the following format: `<GSI-prefix>-<zone code>-<publisher code>-<publication code>-<checksum>`

Publisher code can be a 2 to 7 digits number. You cannot tell just by reading the whole ISBN code.